# Function one to one

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

If $f$and $g$ is one to one then ${f×g}$ and ${f+g}$ is one to one

Is this true? If not, I need some clarification to understand

Thanks

Comment: Suppose $f=-g$.

Answer (score 2):

No. For the first take 
$$
f(x)=x,\;g(x)=-x
$$
making $f+g\equiv 0$.

For the second, take $f(x)=g(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = x$, and $g(x) = x$. Then $f,g$ are one-to-one, but $fg$ is not one-to-one.

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = x$, and $g(x) = -x$. Then $f,g$ are one-to-one, but $f+g$ is not one-to-one.

To the OP:

What are the simplest functions which you know are one-to-one? Linear functions, right? To test the truth of a potential claim, it makes sense to first spot-check the claim by trying a few simple examples.

Comment: yikes, I guess these were the most obvious ones

Comment: Nothing wrong with using obvious ones.

Answer (score 0):

Well consider f(x) = x and g(x) = x^3 
Both the functions are one-one but f × g is not an one- one function but f+g is one - one.

Answer (score 0):

One to one means that if $f(a) = k$ and $f(b) = k$ then $a=b$.

So if $f(a) + g(a) = k + j = m$ and $f(b) + g(b) = l + h = m$ does it follow that $a = b$ and that $k = l$ and $j = h$?

What if $f(a) = k; g(a) = j$ but $f(b) = j$ and $g(b) = k$.  Is that ever possible?  Why wouldn't it be?

And easy counter example if $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 5 -x$ so $f(x) + g(x) = x + 5 -x = 5$.  That's clearly not one to one.